# Java: Socket close connection and ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, sockets, connection, objectinputstream

My code looks like this, this is Server code (`Runnable`)

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for client...");
            this.socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Client accepted");
            while (true) {
                readCommand();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Main.error("Server stopped for current host", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is: when the client closes the connection, he still waiting to read the command in `readCommand();` until a command was sent and an `EOFException` will be thrown. This is my `readCommand` method:

```
private void readCommand() throws Exception {
    Object o = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()).readObject();
    if (o instanceof Command) {
        ((Command) o).execute();
        return;
    }
    if (o instanceof Recorder) {
        System.out.println("Recording received");
        ((Recorder) o).executeRecord();
        return;
    }
    if (o instanceof MyKeyEvent) {
        ((MyKeyEvent) o).execute();
        return;
    }
}
```

So I think before reading it has to check if the connection is open.

**Edit:** If I evaluate the `run`-method code, the `EOFException` is thrown in the `try-catch-body`. But he stops accepting clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `EOFException` is exactly what I'd expect if the client closes the connection. So I'm not quite sure what your problem actually *is*. Perhaps you need to distinguish between an expected client disconnect and an unexpected client disconnect. In which case you should perhaps send some sort of `End-of-message` object to mark the end of transmission ?

If you want to check if info is available, there's an [available()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#available%28%29) method on the stream. I don't think you need your `Thread.sleep(2)`, btw, since I would expect a read on a **valid** input stream to hang in the absence of data.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux I don't see why you think you need a two-microsecond sleep, but you don't. Nor do you need an extra object to signal EOS when you already have EOFException.

Comment: @EJP: Probably, yes. Take a look at the date of posting this. I don't remember anything of that project. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also "just" add another try-catch to catch just the EOFException

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for client...");
            this.socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Client accepted");
            try {
                while (true) {
                    readCommand();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            } catch (EOFException ex) {
                System.out.println("client closed");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Main.error("Server stopped for current host", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

sure, the End-of-command is much smarter/elegant...
[]]

Comment: Or just an extra catch. You don't need the second 'try'.